# Is there a way to get each array sliced inside a NumPy array with different begin and end

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
```

is there a way to slice each subarray in X with diffrent begin and end indexes
Something like this

```
#np.eg_slic(X, [[begin,end],[begin,end]])
np.eg_slice(X, [[1,3],[0,2]])
>>> array([[2,3],[5,6]])
```

I am currently using linspace to generate every index value and store it in array which is not really efficient when it comes to ram size

Comment: All the slices would have the same length? Is the expected output a "normal" (not jagged) numpy array?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yeah All the slices would have the same length and expected output would be normal.

Comment: I can guess how you are using `linspace`, but it might help if you showed it.  But if you don't want to loop row by row, you will need to construct an advanced indexing array, and linspace  is handy way of doing that.

Comment: The fast compiled numpy methods often do create large temporary buffers.  That's a integral part of its convenient building block approach.  Write your own compiled code if you are really worried about memory use.

Comment: `masking` as suggested in the answer uses one  (or more) arrays the same size as `X`.  Advanced indexing just uses an array the same size as the final result.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by creating a mask based on the `start` and `end` indices of the slice array.

inputs :

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
indices = np.array([[1,3],[0,2]])
```

Split the indices to get the `start` and `end` indices for each row,

```
start,end = np.hsplit(indices,2)
#start: ([[1],[0]]),
#end:  ([[3],[2]])
```

Mask creation,

```
 jj = np.arange(X.shape[1])[None,...]

 mask = (jj >= start)* (jj < end)
 #[[False,  True,  True, False],
   [ True,  True, False, False]]
```

Get the values,

```
 X[mask].reshape(-1,2) # reshape based on slice length
 #[[2, 3],
   [5, 6]]
```

Comment: This uses a lot more memory that the advanced indexing that (I think) the OP is using.  `jj` `mask` and each of the intermediate arrays have the same size as `X`.  You should be able create `mask` using the two `aranges` and broadcasting, without the repeats.  I think the OP is using `np.linspace` to make the equivalent of `np.nonzero(mask)`.